# Rotate picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms

how in windows forms rotate picturebox element at 45 degrees

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Graphics.RotateTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.rotatetransform.aspx) on the image.

```
Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(myImage);
graphic.RotateTransform(45);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/RotatePictureBox.aspx in that they clearly explained with sample

Answer (score 0):

For the picture inside the picturebox, use Bitmap.FlipRotate method.